# error " cannot execute binary file"

Tags: binary

I have mibconverter file(mibcomp.exe) and it works fine on Ubuntu 12.04 but it has error on 14.04 and upper version(16).

I have run on same machine so it is not possibly architecture problem.

Error:
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error".

Is it possible I can fix the problem?

Thank you,

Insuk

Comment: Add the output of the following commands to your question as an edit:on your 12.04 and 14.04/16.04 systems: `uname -a`, and then also show us the output of the following info from the 12.04 system: `file mibcomp.exe`

Comment: It looks like architecture is different although I installed the 32bit for 14.04. For 12.04:

uname -a result :
 Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-82-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 27 21:24:19 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux   ,

file mibcomp.exe
 mibcomp.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows


 For 14.04

uname -a
 Linux ubuntu 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:27 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: So which iso should I install for 14.04 in order to match i686 i686 i386? Thanks

Comment: When I looked 14.04 LTS : setting -> Details -> Overview -> OS type 32bit. thanks

Comment: You need the 32bit ISO for the OS to work.

Comment: As I wrote it, it shows as OS type 32 bit when I looked at system information and I remember I chose the 32 bit ISO when I installed. Do you know why it happened. Thanks

Comment: It sounds to me like it'd be a Wine issue.  Mostly, because Windows executables need Wine to work, and you might not have Wine.  Or, newer Wine doesn't work with the executable.

Comment: After installing wine on Ubuntu 14.04, it is working without the error. Thank you so much. But I have still question if my OS type is 32bit or 64bit since the command results looks like 64 bit and system information shows as 32 bit. Do you have any insight about that? Thank you